# Convert view to bitmap

Tags: android, user-interface, bitmap

I have a view I want to create a bitmap for that view(later I want to print that bitmap). What I have tried is as follows

```
private Bitmap convertViewToBitMap() {      
    View v = rootView;   //rootView is my view to be converted in bitmap
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
    return b;
}
```

My view "rootview" is a expandable list, when I call `convertViewToBitMap()`, I get the bitmap of view which is visible on screen, but if view is expanded, the expanded part which is going out of screen does not come in bitmap. So is there a way to get a bitmap of complete view even if it is partially visible on screen?

Comment: I don't think so. For performance reasons most of things off screen are not calculated/displayed. For example in a listView, the cells are recycled. If you have 10 cells displayed, 12 will be calculated to allow the scroll and when a cell goes off the screen it is recycled. Therefore I don't think that in you case it is possible to  have the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Make some adjustments to your view. "Measure" method  defines the proper dimensions of your view (change 1000 and 600 to what suits you best)

   ```
   view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1000, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
   ```
2. Re-define your view with the new measurements (change also 0,0)

   ```
            view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
   ```
3. Create the bitmap

   ```
            Bitmap bm=Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   ```

After that, you can draw your bitmap to any view

```
               Canvas cn=new Canvas(bm); 
               anyview.draw(cn);
```

Also, you can save the bitmap into a file

```
           try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```